# jQuery Fade in trouble (Works in second rotation but not first)

Tags: jquery, fadein

Ok, I mostly deal with content and some front end design but I was trying to throw together a nice image slider to iFrame into our website. I was able to construct it using jQuery but I am having a small problem with it. It is supposed to have a fade in and a fade out but during its first rotation it only uses the fade out. The next rotation it works perfectly.

Here is the code I'm using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  slideShow();
});

function slideShow() {

  var showing = $('#ContentContain2 .isshowing');
  var next = showing.next().length ? showing.next() : showing.parent().children(':first');

  showing.fadeOut(800, function() { next.fadeIn(1600).addClass('isshowing'); }).removeClass('isshowing');

  setTimeout(slideShow, 5000);
}

</script>
```

Here is a link to it hosted so you can see the problem.

http://ksee.bimedia.net/sites/community/index.html

Comment: Did you hide the images before running the plugin? You can't fade something in that is already visible!

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding them all first (before you fade them in). I think that's the culprit, which would explain why they fade in after being faded out in the first cycle (but not before). You can't "fade in" from full opacity.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ContentContain2").children("img").not(".isshowing").hide(); // hide em
  slideShow();
});

function slideShow() {

  var showing = $('#ContentContain2 .isshowing');
  var next = showing.next().length ? showing.next() : showing.parent().children(':first');

  showing.fadeOut(800, function() { next.fadeIn(1600).addClass('isshowing'); }).removeClass('isshowing');

  setTimeout(slideShow, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add the following to a css file (or just apply the style to the individual elements):

```
#ContentContain2 img
{
display: none;
}

#ContentContain2 img.isshowing
{
display: inline;
}
```

This will effectively do what Set Sail suggested to do with code: it'll hide the elements until fadeIn is called.

Also, are you aware that img2 is the first thing that is actually being displayed? If you want img1 to show first, I'd move your `isshowing` class to img4 so the script fades img1 in to begin with.

edit:
Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/Efbt3/